# Getting old-entity with JPA (Hibernate)

Tags: java, jsf, jpa

I am getting old entity-data with JPA displayed in my JSF-Page, even if I disable the second-level-cache of hibernate.

There are three entities: MessageEntities contain DataEntities and those contain SubDataEntities.

SubDataEntities are extended by two different types.

I temporary delete an instance of SubDataEntity by setting its data-attribute to null and remove the instance from the collection in parent-entity (DataEntity).
After ajax-request, the old data is still displayed in JSF-Page, also if I really execute a successfull delete-operation on DB.

MessageEntity:

```
@Entity(name = "Message")
@Table(name = "message")
public class MessageEntity {


  @Column(name = "version")
  private String               version;

  @Column(name = "variant")
  private String               variant; 

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "message", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<DataEntity> data;
```

DataEntity:

```
@Entity(name = "Data")
@Table(name = "data")
public class DataEntity {

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "messageId")
  private MessageEntity     message;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "data", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<SubDataEntity> subData;
```

SubDataEntity:

```
@Entity(name = "SubData")
@Table(name = "subData")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class SubDataEntity implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(unique = true, name = "sd_id")
  private Integer            id;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
  @JoinColumn(name = "dataId")
  private DataEntity         data;

  @Column(name = "value")
  private String             value;
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The failure was caused be cause the attribute "immediate" was set to true in the component, that was displaying and editing the value for. 
After switching on process="@this" and process="@form".

Comment: This cannot be seen from the original question so this Q and A is kind of not very useful since it might depend on other parts of the code that are not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it was due to caching of first level..
Try evicting the cache when you are loading the data..

```
getEntityManager().getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
```

Comment: @PrashantKantara Thanks for your advice. Unfortunately cleaning the chache doesn't effect the result, neither when removing the entity nor when loading the data.